# Django Tutorial instructions seem wrong for lattest version

Tags: python, django

I am following the tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/ for Django and I have ran the to commands as such. I am new to Django and reasonable new to phython development coming from a c# background.

> python -m pip install Django

> django-admin startproject mysite

> python manage.py startapp polls

I ran the second one while in mysite now when I look at my directory structure it doesnt include the urls object

[image]

But yet the mysite folder does?.

[image]

Yet acording to the way the site shows it it does is there something im missing.

[image]

Comment: you can see on your tutorial image that there is no urls.py inside of app directory, although it is your project directory as you startproject

Comment: The tutorial says to create the `urls.py` in the [Write Your First View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view) section: *To create a URLconf in the polls directory, create a file called urls.py.*

Answer (score 2):

Django does not create urls.py by default in a new app, because not all apps need them.

In your polls directory create a urls.py file.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlspatterns = [
    path("view", views.poll_view_function)
]
```

Then in the mysite folder connect this app's urls configuration to the project.

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls"))
]
```

This would be accessed with /polls/view

Documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: bbut why does the documentation show this In the polls/urls.py file include the following 
 In the polls/urls.py file include the following code:

: 

 is it outdated

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view In this section is says to create the urls.py file: "This is the simplest view possible in Django. To call the view, we need to map it to a URL - and for this we need a URLconf. To create a URLconf in the polls directory, create a file called urls.py."

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start a new app it does not include the `urls.py`. The url dispatcher will use the URL patterns in your site folder unless you use an `include` function and add `urls.py` to your specific apps (which I suggest to easily manage urls). And you can simply just create a new `.py` file with the name `urls` in the app folder.